# Particle in a cylinder with a spring, sign convention in potential energy (Lagrangian multipliers)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, spring

I'm trying to get the force of constraint. The problem I have is when defying the sign of the potential energy using cylindrical coordinates $(\rho,\phi,z)$, what I have is:
$$
V=mgy-\frac{1}{2}k\left(\rho^2+R\rho \sin\phi+\left(\frac{R}{2}\right)^2+z^2\right)=
$$
$$
=mg\rho\sin{\phi}-\frac{1}{2}k\left(\rho^2+R\rho \sin\phi+\left(\frac{R}{2}\right)^2+z^2\right).
$$
But the solution in theory is:
$$
V=-mg\rho\sin{\phi}-\frac{1}{2}k\left(\rho^2+R\rho \sin\phi+\left(\frac{R}{2}\right)^2+z^2\right).
$$
I don't get why $mg\sin{\phi}$ is negative, considering the axes in the frame of reference from the diagram below, shouldn't be positive if the $y$-axis has the same direction as the gravity.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the $y-$axis is pointing downwards, the height will increase when the $y$ coordinate decreases, so the correct gravitational potential energy is $V_g=-mgy$, as it is greater at higher height.

You can check it this way:
The azimuthal angle $\phi$ is usually defined from the $x-$axis, so $V_g=-mgy=-mg\rho\sin\phi$ will be minimum when $\phi=\pi/2$ (the situation of the diagram) and maximum when $\phi=3\pi/2.$

Comment: Sorry, I see  what you mean by azimuthal angle but I still don't comprehend why is $-mg\rho\sin{\phi}$ and not $mg\rho\sin{\phi}$.

Comment: Gravitational potential energy is greater at higher height, so its maximum has to be when $\phi=3\pi/2$ and its minimum at $\phi=\pi/2$.